# Nginx with wordpress, use reverse proxy as fallback

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup nginx to try files in the following order:

1) See if file exists directly on server
2) See if file exists as part of wordpress
3) Fallback to external server if neither 1 or 2 exist.

I have the following setup:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass      https://external.website.com;
}
```

This doesn't work for wordpress, and nginx's try_files documentation  is pretty unhelpful. I can see that whichever arg is last is the fallback, so I tried flipping the last two args, and that caused wordpress to work, but then the reverse proxy didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. Technically this checks the proxy first, but that's okay for what I want to do. If anyone solves the correct way, I will choose them.

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass      https://external.website.com;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        error_page 404 = @wordpress;
    }

    location @wordpress{
        try_files $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```